# Trying to use wxPython on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wxpython

I have installed wxPython on my RPi using

```
sudo pip3 install wxPython-4.0.7.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

But when I attempt to run my python program (which works on my windows machine), I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TrainingUI.py", line 2, in <module>
    import wx.media
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wx/media.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._media import *
ImportError: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I see that the `media.py` file has the `from ._media import *` line in it, but I don't know what it means. I used `ls -a` to see that there is no file named `._media`, and I'm not experienced enough with python to know what else it might refer to.

How can I get this wx distribution to work with my python3.7 on the RPi?

Comment: Might be trying to import from _media.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so; does this exist?

Comment: No, I have _media.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so - is that any help?

Comment: What version of gstreamer do you have loaded on that Pi box. It looks suspiciously like it needs the old version 0.10 not the latest 1.0

Comment: we finally found a 0.10 package to load, so the import error is gone. I have not played a video yet; am crafting a different question for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We (eventually) found:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
```

and the error when wx.media is imported is now gone. We can't get MediaCtrl to work, but that's for another post...